# Clarification on one question in Spivak's Calculus

Tags: calculus

Problem 1 vii) of Chapter 7 in Spivak's ***Calculus*** defines a function as follows:

> $f(x)=\begin{cases} 0, & \text{$x$ is irrational}\\ \frac{1}{q}, & \text{$x=p/q$ in lowest terms}\end{cases}\\ \text{on} \,x\in [0, 1].$

Just wondering what is the value of $f(0)$.

Comment: $1$? $\quad0=0/1$

Comment: It is 0. You have 0=0/3 for instance

Comment: But is 0/3 in lowest terms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither $0$ nor $1$ are irrational numbers, so $f(0) \ne 0$ and $f(1) \ne 0$.  As for what it means by "lowest terms," the idea is that a nonnegative rational number can be uniquely expressed as the ratio of integers $p$ and $q$ such that $p \ge 0$ and $q > 0$, such that $q$ is as small as possible.  In the case of $0$, the lowest terms rational would have $p = 0$ and $q = 1$.  Indeed, for any positive integer $n$, the lowest terms rational expression is simply $p = n$ and $q = 1$.  This also answers the question of the value of $f(1)$.  This can be generalized to negative rationals as well, by allowing $p \in \mathbb Z$ and $q > 0$ such that again, $q$ is minimal.

Comment: The reason $0/2$ is not in lowest terms is $\gcd (0,2)=2>1.$...............+1